# JSON parsing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to extract data from the result of a Google Places call.

If I run the following Javascript:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(places[0].geometry.location));
```

I get the following output, as expected:

```
{"lat":59.9138688,"lng":10.752245399999993}
```

However if I put .lat on the end to extract the lat value and run:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(places[0].geometry.location.lat));
```

I get:

```
undefined
```

And if I run the alert without the JSON.stringify as follows:

```
alert(places[0].geometry.location.lat);
```

I get:

```
function (){return a}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to stringify places[0].geometry.location.lat. it already returns a number.
If you want to make it a string you can use `places[0].geometry.location.lat.toString()`

Comment: I'm guessing that your `location` object has a `toJSON` method that calls the `lat` and `lng` functions when it's being serialized. What does `places[0].geometry.location.toJSON` show?

Comment: No toJSON method as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do this:

```
alert(places[0].geometry.location.lat());
```

Comment: That does the trick thanks. Why does it need () on the end though?

Comment: @BillNoble because lat is a function and must call it

Comment: Why is lat a function when the datastructure is: {"lat":59.9138688,"lng":10.752245399999993}

Comment: @BillNoble it is google map api structure and lat function return lat property

Comment: Ah! Thanks for taking the time to explain this to me it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify` - Is a function that usually accepts an object (although, it can get more types).
In your case, it takes a Number, since `places[0].geometry.location.lat` is a Number and **not** an Object.

Therefore, if you want to get a string you should use the `.toString()` function that comes with the Number prototype.

Try `alert(places[0].geometry.location.lat.toString())`